# C# Resolve and Close Tickets

Tags: c#

Can anyone help me with this:
I have written a simple ticketing system code using C#, I think I've confused myself a n little here. I need to be able to provide a response on the Admin desk side, resolve (adding admin comments) and close tickets.

I have already created lists = Created (total tickets) | Resolved (closed) | To Solve (open/reopened) - will populate this later.

What I am struggling with is how and where to reopen > resolves (provide response) > close tickets?

Any help would be most appreciated, I have tried quite few tutorials, and options and I just can't seem to figure it out.

`Program Class`

```
using System;
using Ticket_System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Ticket_System
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Ticket> Open = new List<Ticket>();
            List<Ticket> Closed = new List<Ticket>();
            List<Ticket> Reopened = new List<Ticket>();

            //Help Desk - Submit Ticket

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter 1 for Help Desk");
            int option1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (option1 == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("************************************");
                Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Welcome to the Help Desk\n");
                string running = "yes";
                while (running == "yes")
                {
                    Ticket objticket;

                    Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Please enter your first name: ");
                    string b_creator = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Please enter your Staff ID (first name + first letter of last name):");
                    string b_staffid = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Please enter your email address: ");
                    string b_email = Console.ReadLine(); 

                    Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Please enter a brief description of issue: ");
                    string b_description = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Ticket Status: ");
                    string b_status = "Open" ;
                                        
                    if (b_creator + b_email == "")
                    {
                        objticket = new Ticket (b_staffid, b_description, b_status);

                    }
                    else if (b_description == "Password change")
                    {
                        objticket = new Ticket(b_creator, b_staffid, b_email, b_description);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        objticket = new Ticket(b_creator, b_staffid, b_email, b_description, b_status);
                    }

                    Open.Add(objticket);

                    Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Do you want to submit another issue (yes or no)");
                    running = Console.ReadLine();                                    

                }
            }
            //Admin Desk

            Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Please enter 2 for Admin Desk");
            int option2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (option2 == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("************************************");
                Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Welcome to Admin Desk");
                Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Tickets Created: " + "Tickets Resolved: " + "Tickets to Solve:");
                int ticket_count = Open.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < ticket_count; i++)
                {
                    Open[i].show_info();
                }

                Console.WriteLine("************************************");


                Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Do you want respond to Open tickets (yes or no)");
                string option3 = Console.ReadLine();
                if (option3 == "yes")
                {                       
                    string running = "yes";
                    while (running == "yes")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Please enter ticket number");
                        int change_status = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        for (int i = 0; i < ticket_count; i++)
                        {
                            Ticket tempobj = Open[i];
                            if(tempobj.nTicket == change_status)
                            {
                                tempobj.status = "Closed";
                                Closed.Add(tempobj);
                                Open.Remove(tempobj);
                                ticket_count--;
                                i--;
                                
                            }
                                                   }
                        Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Do you want to continue (yes or no)");
                        running = Console.ReadLine();

                    }                                 
                                  
                }
                Console.WriteLine("************************************");
                Console.WriteLine("Open Tickets\n");

                int ticket_count1 = Open.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < ticket_count1; i++)
                {
                    Open[i].show_info();
                }
                                
                Console.WriteLine("************************************");
                Console.WriteLine("Closed Tickets");

                int closed_list_count = Closed.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < closed_list_count; i++)
                {
                    Closed[i].show_info();
                }                
                Console.WriteLine("************************************");
```

`Ticket Class`

```
using System;
namespace Ticket_System
{
    public class Ticket
        
    {
        public static int ticket_number = 2000;
        public int nTicket;
        public string creator;
        public string staffid;
        public string email;
        public string description;
        public string response;
        public string status;
                    
        //TicketClass

        public Ticket (string a_creator, string a_staffid, string a_email, string a_description, string a_status)
        {
            creator = a_creator;
            staffid = a_staffid;
            email = a_email;
            description = a_description;
            status = a_status;
            ticket_number++;
            nTicket = ticket_number;            
        }

        public Ticket (string a_staffid, string a_description, string a_status)
        {
            creator = "Not Specified";
            staffid = a_staffid;
            email = "Not Specified";
            description = a_description;
            status = a_status;
            ticket_number++;
            nTicket = ticket_number;
        }

        public Ticket(string a_creator, string a_staffid, string a_email, string a_description)
        {
            creator = a_creator;
            staffid = a_staffid;
            email = a_email;
            description = a_description;
            status = "Closed";
            ticket_number++;
            nTicket = ticket_number;
        }

        //PasswordGenerator Class

        public string Password_Change(string name)
        {
            string time_stamp = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("X");
            string new_password = staffid.Substring(0, 2) + ticket_number.ToString("X") + time_stamp.Substring(0, 3);
            return new_password;

        }

        public void show_info()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Ticket Number: " + nTicket);
            Console.WriteLine("Ticket Creator: " + creator);
            Console.WriteLine("Staff ID: " + staffid);
            Console.WriteLine("Email Address: " + email);
            Console.WriteLine("Description: " + description);
            Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Ticket Status: " + status);
            if (description.Contains("Password change"))
            {
                string new_password = Password_Change(staffid);
                Console.WriteLine("Response: " + "New password generated: " + new_password);

            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n************************************\n");
```

Comment: Seems yoy have a little menu flow structure problem, I propose that you use tree menu flow instead a sequential one, so you can put the reopen option _inside_ the correct parent  menu. Hint you probably need to use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements#the-switch-statement)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).